# How can I overwrite Python 3.x 32-bit with Python 3.x 64-bit on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, upgrade

I have only installed Python 3 on this Windows computer, starting with Python 3.6.4 32-bit.

Today I installed Python 3.6.5 64-bit using the [".exe" installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5-amd64.exe), but when I ran `python` in my Command Prompt, it still shows Python 3.6.4.

I tried restarting my computer and using the "repair" function on the installer, but that didn't change anything.

When I look in `C:\Users\UserNameHere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\` as per [this comment](http://C:%5CUsers%5CUserNameHere%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CPrograms%5CPython%5C), the only folder I see is `Python36-32`, which is obviously not the 64-bit version I just installed.

I did some searching and found out that if I run `C:/Windows/py.exe`, this will launch Python 3.6.5. However, I can't seem to find the right way to get this to be the normal command.

How can I get the `python` command to run Python 3.6.5, and how can I get `pip` to recognize I'm running Python 3.6.5 64-bit so that it finds and uses the correct wheels?

Comment: For now, I will just be using `py.exe -m pip` to use pip, and `py.exe` to run python programs.